# How to increase performance in neo4j?

Tags: performance, configuration, neo4j

I am using embedded `neo4j 1.9.3`, there will be

---

- Nodes: 300 million
- Relationships: 600 million
- Properties per-node: 1
- Properties per-relationship: 1

---

My machine has:

- RAM: 8 GB
- HDD: 1 TB
- CPU: 2.20 ghz

---

My configuration is:

- -Xms4g
- -Xmx6g
- -XX:+UseG1GC
- dbms.pagecache.memory = 4g
- -XX:+UseG1GC

---

I am using Java API for writing and query operations. Query speed is quite well but writing speed is very slow. What would be the reason? What configurations should I add for having efficient writing speed?

Here is writing part in my code:

```
private static IndexManager  index = Graph.graphDB.index();
private static Index<Node> allNodes = index.forNodes("allnodes");  

public Node create(String value) {
    Node node = super.getOrCreate("name", value);
    return node;
}

public void createNode() {
    try {
        Transaction tx = Graph.graphDB.beginTx();

        Node subject = create(RDF.getInstance().getSubject().toString());
        Node object = create(RDF.getInstance().getObject().toString());
        Node predicate = create(RDF.getInstance().getPredicate().toString());

        Node factNode = Graph.graphDB.createNode();

        factNode.createRelationshipTo(subject, RelTypes.SUBJECT);
        factNode.createRelationshipTo(predicate, RelTypes.PREDICATE);
        factNode.createRelationshipTo(object, RelTypes.OBJECT);

        allNodes.add(subject, "name", subject.getProperty("name"));
        allNodes.add(predicate, "name", predicate.getProperty("name"));
        allNodes.add(object, "name", object.getProperty("name"));

        tx.success();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You forgot `tx.finish()`, so your transaction is never closed/comitted.**

Probably your disk is too slow. Use a SSD.
Make sure to disable virus scanners / disk encryption.

It would also make sense to have a more memory available, e.g. 16G.

Currently you are probably **swapping to disk** as you use 4+6G = 10G on a 8G machine.
Reduce heap to 2G and page-cache to 5G. So you have 1G for OS and JVM.

In general storing a RDF model in a property graph doesn't make a lot of sense.
Try to create a proper property graph model and import **into it**.

**Also I recommend to upgrade to the latest version of Neo4j 2.3.1.**

Or your code is not very efficient esp. these lines:

```
    Node subject = create(RDF.getInstance().getSubject().toString());
    Node object = create(RDF.getInstance().getObject().toString());
    Node predicate = create(RDF.getInstance().getPredicate().toString());

    allNodes.add(subject, "name", subject.getProperty("name"));
    allNodes.add(predicate, "name", predicate.getProperty("name"));
    allNodes.add(object, "name", object.getProperty("name"));
```

Does it make sense to add everything to an index? Why?

You should also have more efficient code to access the properties, why pull it out of RFD first and then again pull it out of the property? 
Store the values in a variable.

Comment: should I use tinkerpop, or there is better one? And which tool is efficient for importing large rdf triple set to property graph?

Comment: Use the Neo4j APIs directly. If you model a sensible property graph model, import your RDF structures *INTO* it.

Comment: thanks for this. Could you please share some link about it?